# Change background color in header and footer Clean Retina WordPress theme

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, background-color

Clean Retina supports Custom Background Feature.

Go to Appearance->Header.
You can either set the image or color as background.
You can see the background preview on the same setting page.
Click on Save Changes.
NOTE:The background effect will only change the content part but not in the header and footer part. ***If you want the change to reflect in the header and footer as well then write your custom CSS in Appearance->Theme Options->Design Options->Custom CSS input field to hide the Header and Footer pattern. And Save the Changes.***

Well this is what i want to do, change the color of the Header and Footer background. I have no experience with CSS and been searching the Internet and tried a quite a few different codes, wich did not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using it stock which by your post I assume you are the following needs to be added.

```
#branding{background-color:blue;}
#colophon{background-color:blue;}
```

You have to make sure to remove the current background CSS for both those options, they have an image applied which will hide the background-color. If that doesn't work, or you can't access the stylesheet to remove those properties just use the background property and overwrite the current one in the hierarchy like below:

```
#branding{background:blue;}
#colophon{background:blue;}
```

Obviously choose your own colour.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing from your question that you're very new to web design, so I'll try and explain things as simply as possible.

HTML pages are built up from *elements* (or *tags*) such as `<div>`, `<span>`, `<p>`, and so on. Most elements must have an opening tag (e.g. `<div>`) and a closing tag (normally containing a slash, e.g. `</div>`). the information between these tags is the element's content, which can be any number of other elements, or just text.

Elements can have *classes* or *IDs*, which are what CSS uses to identify which parts of the page you want to change the 'look and feel' of (as well as being used as hooks for Javascript or anchors for links, but we won't go into that now).

A *class* (e.g. `<div class="someClass">...</div>`) can be used multiple times on the same page and is prefixed in CSS with a period (`.`). Any CSS rules that you write for that class will be applied to every instance of that class. For instance:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .someClass {
        color: red;
    }
</style>

<div class="someClass">Content</div>
<div class="anotherClass">Content</div>
<div class="someClass">Content</div>
```

This code will turn the text in the first and last `<div>`s red.

*IDs* are designed to be unique on the page. These are prefixed in CSS with a hash (`#`).

For example:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .someClass {
        color: red;
    }

    #myId {
        color: green;
    }
</style>

<div class="someClass" id="myId">Content</div>
<div class="anotherClass">Content</div>
<div class="someClass">Content</div>
```

Will result in the first `<div>`'s text being green, as *IDs* are more 'important' than *classes*, as well as the fact that the CSS for `#myId` comes after the `.someClass` declaration (rules lower down a stylesheet overwrite those further up, if the level of importance is the same). As an example of this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .someClass {
        color: red;
    }

    .someClass {
        color: black;
    }
</style>

<div class="someClass" id="myId">Content</div>
<div class="anotherClass">Content</div>
<div class="someClass">Content</div>
```

Will result in the first and last `<div>`'s text being black, as we overwrite our first declaration.

Now! On to your specific question.

What you need to do is find out what the *IDs* for the theme's header and footer are (I would not be surprised if they're `#header` and `#footer`). Then, all you need to do in a CSS file is:

```
#headerId {
    background-color: yourColour;
}

#footerId {
    background-color: yourColour;
}
```

(where `#headerId` and `#footerId` are the *IDs* of the header and footer, and `yourColour` is the Hex code (or plaintext name) of your chosen colour.)

Hope this helps...